# Postgresql - PHP - Recorrer Array e insertar en base de datos dependiendo de cada linea del array

Tags: array, postgresql, sql, select, insert

Tengo un array donde veo los valores de una consulta especifica de la tabla1

```
$sql = pg_query("SELECT  fecha,tramo, sentido FROM tabla1 where tramo>= 1 and 
tramo<= 10 ");

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
    $tramo = $row['tramo'];
    $sentido = $row['sentido'];

$listado[] = array('fecha'=> $fecha, 'tramo'=> $tramo, 'sentido'=> $sentido);
```

Luego necesito insertar dentro de la tabla2 dependiendo de cada línea obtenida del array de la tabla1:

por ejemplo: si la línea [0] del array es (fecha 2019-01-01,tramo es "2" y sentido es "Norte") entonces esos valores pasarlos al insert que contiene un select anidado con más datos e ir linea por linea hasta llegar al final.

```
   pg_query("INSERT INTO tabla2(id, fecha, flujo,tramo) SELECT 
   id,fecha,flujo,tramo FROM test2 where tramo = '$tramo' and fecha = '$fecha'");


print_r($listado);
```

Ahora mismo lo único que hace el código mostrar el array con el print_r pero no es capaz de insertar nada.

```
    Array
    (
           [0] = Array
      (
           [fecha] =2011-09-01 18:56:00-03
           [tramo] = 250000
           [sentido] = Sur
     )

[1] = Array
    (
        [fecha] = 2011-09-01 19:09:00-03
        [tramo] = 250001
        [sentido] = Centro
    )

[2] = Array
    (
        [fecha] = 2011-09-01 19:12:00-03
        [tramo] = 250002
        [sentido] = Norte
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Dentro del mismo `while` que lee los primeros resultados puedes ir construyendo los múltiples `INSERT` en una variable, y luego le pasas esa variable al manejador para que se inserten los datos.

Sería simplemente esto:

```
/* Variable que reunirá los INSERT */
$multiInsert="";
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
    $tramo = $row['tramo'];
    $sentido = $row['sentido'];
    /* 
       Concatenamos cada fila con .= 
       NÓTESE que cada sentencia de la cadena termina con ; (dentro de las comillas)
    */
    $multiInsert.="INSERT INTO tabla2(id, fecha, flujo,tramo) SELECT 
   id,fecha,flujo,tramo FROM test2 where tramo = '$tramo' and fecha = '$fecha';";
}
```

Luego ejecutas:

```
pg_query($multiInsert);
```

### Algunas observaciones:

1. Si los valores de `$tramo` y `$fecha` están al alcance del usuario y pueden ser modificados por éste, conviene que uses consultas preparadas, de lo contrario el código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.
2. Si la columna `tramo` es numérica, debes poner la consulta así: `where tramo = $tramo`, es decir, sin rodear `$tramo` de comillas simples.
3. Para inserciones o modificaciones masivas, conviene usar transacciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono--- y gracias por tus observaciones, los tendre en cuenta.

Comment: @MauricioAndrésMéndezParada Si te funcionó deberías marcar la pregunta como respondida (marca la respuesta como respuesta correcta para tu pregunta) y así la gente podrá saber que esta pregunta fue respondida. (Aparte de que es una forma de dar reconocimiento al que te ha respondido)